# How to config Tomcat 7.x's environment variables?

Tags: tomcat

I googled it, and find several methods, but they are different,

some people told me that i only need to create the env variable named "CATALINA_HOME",

BUT some told me to create four variables: CATALINA_HOME, CATALINA_BASE, CATALINA_TMPDIR

and TOMCAT_HOME.

which one is right? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your using Eclipse  i would suggest you to run it as an external server,all you have to do is unzipping it in any locating you want and in Eclipse add an new server that point to its location,its is easy work with as an external server

Comment: if it worked for you..you have to vote up for the answer that helped you..if any!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue,

They all need to be set, because its technically ok to have them set to different locations.

Are you doing an Install? I think that these get set by running the configure script.

Let me know if you are still stuck, I spent a bit of time setting up tomcat servers. :)

~ Dan

Comment: i read the conf/startup.bat script, in this script, it set CATALINA_HOME every time u run it. in also calls the script catalina.bat, in catalina.bat, the script set the variable CATALINA_BASE and CATALINA_TMPDIR, in tomcat 4.x and ealier version, CATALIA_HOME is called TOMCAT_HOME. i check the official doc of tomcat, but did not find any tips.    ---Alex

Comment: Oh, so you are using windows? I would say that you should just set both, it wont hurt. They are only environment variables. CATALINA_BASE can be different to CATALINA_HOME though - is there any actual issues you are experiencing?

Comment: In apache-tomcat-7.0.29-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.29\webapps\docs\RUNNING.txt there is many details about the env variales.

Comment: Yep, there will be - a lot of the configure scripts will set them up for you. Are you trying to set up tomcat to run as part of eclipse?